# Flatten data with regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm using a program that pings servers and returns results.  The resulting data in text format is the exact opposite of what I need which is a CSV.  I'm awful at with regex and this seems to me that it would be very complex to flatten out this data.

Data before regex

```
  1.2.  3.  4 |  Min  |  Avg  |  Max  |Std.Dev|Reliab%|
  ----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
  + Cached Name   | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 100.0 |
  + Uncached Name | 0.040 | 0.100 | 0.250 | 0.065 | 100.0 |
  + DotCom Lookup | 0.049 | 0.121 | 0.182 | 0.040 | 100.0 |
  ---<-------->---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
                  sub.domain.com
                Some Provider, LLC

  5.6.  7.  8 |  Min  |  Avg  |  Max  |Std.Dev|Reliab%|
  ----------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
  + Cached Name   | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 100.0 |
  + Uncached Name | 0.040 | 0.100 | 0.250 | 0.065 | 100.0 |
  + DotCom Lookup | 0.049 | 0.121 | 0.182 | 0.040 | 100.0 |
  ---<-------->---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
                  bus.domain2.net
                Some Other Provider, Inc
```

And so on

Here's what I'm trying to extract using regex/sed

```
Domain,Company,IP,Cached Name Min,Cached Name Max,Cached Name Avg,Cached Name Std.Dev,Cached Name Reliab%,IP,Uncached Name Min,Uncached Name Max,Uncached Name Avg,Uncached Name Std.Dev,Uncached Name Reliab%,IP,Cached Name Min,Cached Name Max,Cached Name Avg,Cached Name Std.Dev,Cached Name Reliab%,IP,DotCom Lookup Min,DotCom Lookup Max,DotCom Lookup Avg,DotCom Lookup Std.Dev,DotCom Lookup Reliab%
sub.domain.com,Some Provider - LLC,1.2.3.4,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,100.0,0.040,0.250,0.100,0.065,100.0,0.049,0.182,0.121,0.040,100
bus.domain2.net,Some Other Provider - Inc,5.6.7.8,0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,100.0,0.040,0.250,0.100,0.065,100.0,0.040,0.250,0.100,0.065,100.0,0.049,0.182,0.121,0.040,100.0
```

Is this use-case too complex for regex/sed?  Does anyone have any clue how I'd achieve this?

Comment: Depends on how you define "complex". It is certainly doable, but it is going to result in a long regex.

Comment: [Doable, yes. Should it be done? Most definitely not.](https://regex101.com/r/tdCtpR/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Using sed for this might not be the best choice, but sometimes the circumstances or desires override that thought.

So here is an sed solution:

```
sed -En "s/^\s*([[:digit:]]+\.)\s*([[:digit:]]+\.)\s*([[:digit:]]+\.)\s*([[:digit:]]+)\s*\|.*$/\1\2\3\4\,/;T;{N;N;N;N;s/\n[^|]+\|//g;s/ \| /,/g;s/ \|//;x;N;z;N;N;s/,/ -/g;G;s/\n\s*/,/g;s/^,//;p}" input.txt
```

- look for the line with the "1.2.3.4", IP;
  try to extract the IP, if that fails try next line
  `s/^\s*([[:digit:]]+\.)\s*([[:digit:]]+\.)\s*([[:digit:]]+\.)\s*([[:digit:]]+)\s*\|.*$/\1\2\3\4\,/;T;`
- in case of success `T;{`
- get next few lines and delete (or replace by ",") a lot of unneeded stuff
  `N;N;N;N;s/\n[^|]+\|//g;s/ \| /,/g;s/ \|//;`
- store that in hold space and ignore one following line `x;N;z;`
- get next to lines and sanitize "," `N;N;s/,/ -/g;`
- append what is stored in hold space `G;`
- some makeup to get "," (only) in the right places `s/\n\s*/,/g;s/^,//;`
- print and done `p}`

Output:

```
sub.domain.com,Some Provider - LLC,1.2.3.4, 0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,100.0,0.040,0.100,0.250,0.065,100.0,0.049,0.121,0.182,0.040,100.0  
bus.domain2.net,Some Other Provider - Inc,5.6.7.8, 0.000,0.000,0.000,0.000,100.0,0.040,0.100,0.250,0.065,100.0,0.049,0.121,0.182,0.040,100.0
```

Very similar to desired output, except some " " after the `1.2.3.4,`.
Is that a problem?

(Actually I have doubts that the desired output matches the sample input, can you double check?)